# android - image alignment fault

Tags: java, android, graphics

My program is animating an imageView. This image should be in the very center of the screen. The problem is, that the image isn't in the center at all. I tried to do it with

```
if (x<0) {
                    x = this.getWidth()/2;
                    y = this.getHeight()/2;
                }
```

but the program doesn't give the favored result. is it the wrong way to center it, or what's wrong?

```
public class AnimatedView extends ImageView{

    private Context mContext;
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;
    private int xVelocity = 10;
    private int yVelocity = 5;
    private Handler h;
    private final int FRAME_RATE = 30;
    boolean continueAnimation = true;
    private ImageView imageView;


    private BitmapDrawable ball;
    public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {  
        super(context, attrs);  
        mContext = context;  
        h = new Handler();
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);


        }

    private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(continueAnimation) {
            invalidate(); 
            }
        }
    };

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {  

                ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballrot);
                if (x<0) {
                    x = this.getWidth()/2;
                    y = this.getHeight()/2;
                } 

                    else {
                        x += xVelocity;

                            if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
                                boolean continueAnimation = false;
                            }
                    }

                c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  

                if(continueAnimation) 
                {
                    h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);
                }   

                else {
                        x = this.getWidth()-ball.getBitmap().getWidth();
                }

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate center position programmatically you need to know the size of the object to be centered and container where the object reside.

```
centerx = container.getWidth()/2 - obj.getWidth()/2;
centery = container.getHeight()/2 - obj.getHeight()/2;
```

With assumption that you use top left position of object

Comment: Am I not doing it in the if-statement? X is the Position of the image object and this.getWidth() returns the width of my view in pixels. The same with height

Comment: No. They are different.

Comment: In what way? How do i need to do it in this particular case?

Comment: The object is ball and the container is view. You need to take both object size in calculation

Comment: But `x = this.getWidth()` tells me that `this` is declared as int android.view.View and in combination with the method that it returns the height of my view? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Because you do not take ball size into account

Comment: I see now. Thank you